# how to resolve /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory, with sshkit and rvm on rails4 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rvm, capistrano3, sshkit

I am trying to run rake task `rake entrprise:pull` on remote system 
from Rails application with rake task using sshkit and I am using rvm.

rake task

```
require 'sshkit'
require 'sshkit/dsl'
include SSHKit::DSL

namespace :app do
  desc "pulls the records form remote server"
  task :pull => :environment do
    host = SSHKit::Host.new("username@ip")
    on host do |h|
      within("/home/username/my-rails-app/") do
        execute :rake, "enterprise:pull"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In controller I am calling rake task as follows

```
def index
  %x(rake app:pull)
end
```

rake app:pull attempting to run  `rake enterprise:pull` inside remote system at that time it's throwing `/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory` error

but when I ssh into remote system `ssh username@ip` and if run 'rake enterprise:pull' its working fine. my-rails-app was deployed with capistrano-3 and using rvm.

How to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Check your path setup

Comment: echo $PATH ouput: `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin`